# How to forward fill null values of one column from the values of another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ffill

I am trying to fill the null values within column 'beginning_daily_count' with the previous index value from the 'end_daily_count'. The starting dataset would be:

```
d = {
    'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    'beginning_daily_count': [30, 33, 37, 46, None, 7, 1, None, 2],
    'end_daily_count': [33, 37, 46, 52, 33, 7, 1, 2, 3],
    'foils': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
}
```

and the desired dataset would be:

```
d = {
    'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    'beginning_daily_count': [30, 33, 37, 46, 52, 33, 1, 1, 2],
    'end_daily_count': [33, 37, 46, 52, 33, 7, 1, 2, 3],
    'foils': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
}
```

I have attempted the following ffill() and iloc() methods, but to no avail. I admittedly have little experience with ffill and iloc.

```
d.iloc[beginning_daily_count.isna()].values = d.iloc[d.end_daily_count- 1].values
```

```
d['beginning_daily_count'].transform(lambda x: x.ffill(d['end_daily_count']))
```

Comment: FYI in your original example data, `id` and `foils` only had 8 items, whereas the other columns had 9 items. I extended `id` and `foils` with their last values to allow `df = pd.DataFrame(d)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) the column with the shifted other column **per group** (using [`GroupBy.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) to avoid leaking values from one group to the next one):

```
df['beginning_daily_count'] = (df['beginning_daily_count']
                               .fillna(df.groupby('id')['end_daily_count'].shift(),
                                       downcast='infer')
                              )
```

output:

```
   id  beginning_daily_count  end_daily_count  foils
0   1                     30               33      0
1   1                     33               37      0
2   1                     37               46      0
3   1                     46               52      0
4   1                     52               33      0
5   2                      7                7      0
6   2                      1                1      0
7   2                      1                2      1
8   2                      2                3      1
```

Comment: I appreciate you looking beyond the scope of my example, as the dataset I implemented this to certainly would have ran into issues without the groupby. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The [`DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method can accept a series as its first argument, so you can pass it a shifted version of your `end_daily_count` column. Assuming you are OK with potentially sharing data across different `id`s:

```
df['beginning_daily_count'] = df['beginning_daily_count'].fillna(df['end_daily_count'].shift())

print(df)
   id  beginning_daily_count  end_daily_count  foils
0   1                   30.0               33      0
1   1                   33.0               37      0
2   1                   37.0               46      0
3   1                   46.0               52      0
4   1                   52.0               33      0
5   2                    7.0                7      0
6   2                    1.0                1      0
7   2                    1.0                2      1
8   2                    2.0                3      1
```

Comment: This does solve the example I provided, thank you. mozway's addition of groupby brings your solution to completion for slightly more complicated instances.

Answer (score 0):

This will look at the previous index and find the 'end_daily_count' previous when the beginning_daily_count is set to replace

```
df.replace(np.nan, 'Replace', inplace=True)
df['beginning_daily_count'] = np.where(df['beginning_daily_count'] == 'Replace', df.iloc[df.index - 1]['end_daily_count'], df['beginning_daily_count'])
df['beginning_daily_count'] = df['beginning_daily_count'].astype(int)
df
```